# Spectrum of the difference of almost commuting elements

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a C*-algebra. Suppose we have an approximate unit $(u_\lambda)$ then one knows that $|| u_\lambda a-au_\lambda||\rightarrow 0$ in particular  $u_\lambda$ almost commutes with $a$ can one say something about the relation of $sp(u_\lambda-a)$ and $sp(u_\lambda)-sp(a)$ for large enough $\lambda$ ?

I wonder this as if $a$ and $u_\lambda$ actually commuted with each other one would have that $sp(u_\lambda-a)\subseteq sp(u_\lambda)-sp(a)$.

Comment: Do you mean set differences when you say $sp(u_\lambda) - sp(a)$? Or do you mean the set $\{\nu - \eta : \nu  \in sp(u), \eta \in sp(a)\}$

Comment: I mean the second set you stated.